# content doesn't append to div after hover

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/A3uMK/

Hover the links, the content in `<dd>` doesn't appear in the div, anybody mind helping?

Comment: Uh, i'm positive it is, its a definition list ... to the person who just deleted his comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you hide the div tag at the beginning, you need to show it later to see its contents.

```
var $desc = $('div'),
    $dd = $('dl > dd');

$desc.add($dd).hide();

function showDescBox() {
  hideDescBox();
  var $data = $(this).next('dd').html();
  $desc.html($data).show();
}
function hideDescBox() {
  $desc.hide();
}

$('dl > dt').hover(showDescBox, hideDescBox);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A3uMK/8/

Comment: Actually, I need it to hide again after hover off, can you help?

Comment: Stuff it into the open `function()` in `.hover()`. The first function (descBox) is for in, the second is for out.

Comment: Updated so it hides the desc box

Answer (score 4):

That's because the div doesn't appear. You forgot to show the div.

```
$('div').html($data).show();
```